# Convert Color from non-premultiplied alpha to premultiplied alpha

Tags: c#, colors

Is the conversion for a .NET `Color` struct from non-premultiplied alpha to premultiplied alpha:

```
public static Color PremultiplyAlpha(Color pixel) {
    return Color.FromArgb(
        PremultiplyAlpha_Component(pixel.A, pixel.A),
        PremultiplyAlpha_Component(pixel.R, pixel.A),
        PremultiplyAlpha_Component(pixel.G, pixel.A),
        PremultiplyAlpha_Component(pixel.B, pixel.A));
}
private static byte PremultiplyAlpha_Component(byte source, byte alpha) { 
    return (byte)((source * alpha) / byte.MaxValue); 
}
```

Particularly, is it correct to premultiply the alpha component in addition to the RGB components?

Comment: According to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) it is not correct.

Comment: If you are referring to a `System.Drawing.PixelFormat` like e.g. `Format32bppPArgb`, the online documentation says that `the red, green, and blue components are premultiplied, according to the alpha component`, but not the alpha component itself.

Answer (score 0):

As Clemens mentioned - don't divide alpha. Also you're losing some accuracy in the calculation.  <del>Not to mention byte will overflow.</del> Use floats. Then when casting to byte add 0.5 for correct rounding. Or use the built in round.

```
public static Color PremultiplyAlpha(Color pixel) {
    return Color.FromArgb(
        pixel.A,
        PremultiplyAlpha_Component(pixel.R, pixel.A),
        PremultiplyAlpha_Component(pixel.G, pixel.A),
        PremultiplyAlpha_Component(pixel.B, pixel.A));
}
private static byte PremultiplyAlpha_Component(byte source, byte alpha) { 
    return (byte)(float(source) * float(alpha) / float(byte.MaxValue) + 0.5f); 
}
```

Comment: My code can't overflow; `byte.MaxValue*byte.MaxValue` can fit in 32bits signed/unsigned, and that divided by `byte.MaxValue` can fit in 8bits unsigned.

Comment: Guess I'm still living in C.